# I need a good open source and still maintained C/C++ library that can Read/Write (process) .docx and .xlsx files

Tags: c++, c, document-management, documentation-generator, documentation-viewer

As the title says, and sine I am a C++ developer (and mainly using wxWidgets as a toolkit) my purpose for it is to provide an editable reporting application. I will give the users a sample templates with gaps to fill the real data when printing.
So the easy way here is to let them edit the templates via M$ Office or Libre Office.

I know that I can do it using HTML as reporting templates, but not all the users has WYSIWYG HTML editor.

Thank you for your understanding.